# Case statement using date intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I am trying to create a variable that sums sales in 3 months for each customer after their first purchase in the time series. The code below errors and says I'm missing a parentheses.

```
sum(case
  when merch.trans_dt between min(merch.trans_dt) 
    and add_date(min(merch.trans_dt), interval 3 month)
  then merch.rdswrit_rps_netnet_pur_amt
end) as spend_next3
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `then`? But `add_date` isn't an Oracle function, and the interval literal should be `'3'`. Check out the `add_months` function instead.

Comment: I updated the code on here.. it was a copy/paste error

Comment: You want .. `and add_months(min(merch.trans_dt), 3)`  ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simply using addition, rather than a function: `min(merch.trans_dt) + interval 3 month`.

However, this may not give you the answer you want. In many cases, such as `to_date('1/31/2015','mm/dd/yyyy') + interval '3' month`, this will result in `ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified`.

You're better off using `add_months` as indicated previously in the comments: `add_months(min(merch.trans_dt),3)`.